# TensorFlow Keras SavedModel throws a TypeError after being saved and loaded twice

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, serialization, persistence

When I create a Keras model with one or more custom layers, I can use the [`model.save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save) method to persist the Keras model using the TensorFlow [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) format.

I can load this model from the filesystem using [`tf.keras.models.load_model()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) function and save it to the filesystem again.

But when I load the SavedModel from the filesystem a second time, it fails with this exception:

```
TypeError: f(inputs, training, training, training, training, *, training, training) missing 1 required argument: training
```

You can try replicating this issue with the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        return inputs

model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    CustomLayer()
])
model1.build((None, 1))
model1.compile()
model1.save("model1")

model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model("model1")
model2.save("model2")

# This line should raise a TypeError.
model3 = tf.keras.models.load_model("model2")
```

Answer (score 3):

## Why the problem exists

The problem is that the TensorFlow SavedModel format does not actually serialize custom Python code. It only saves the TensorFlow graph generated by custom Keras layers and other Python objects.

The `tf.keras.models.load_model()` function--by default--does not return the Python layer. Instead, it returns a placeholder layer containing the same part of the TensorFlow computation graph. We can see this in the example in my question:

```py
>>> model1.layers
[<__main__.CustomLayer at 0x7ff04c14ee20>]

>>> model2.layers
[<keras.saving.saved_model.load.CustomLayer at 0x7ff114fd7be0>]
```

When `model2` is saved and loaded from the filesystem, TensorFlow cannot correctly parse the `*args` and `**kwargs` arguments in `CustomLayer.call()`.

I don't know whether the actual bug is within the saving code, the loading code, or both.

The real fix needs to happen within TensorFlow/Keras, but in the meantime, there are

## Workarounds

You can choose any ONE of the below workarounds to avoid serialization errors with custom Keras layers.

#### Change the signature on `Layer.call()`

Currently, the official method signature on [`Layer.call()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#call) is `def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):`

But TensorFlow will throw a TypeError when trying to load a model with a custom layer with this signature. To fix the error, write all of your custom layers with a signature of `def call(self, inputs):`. If your layer behaves differently during training or inference, then you can use the method signature `def call(self, inputs, training=None):`

This makes it easier for TensorFlow to generate placeholder layers generated in the `keras.saving.saved_model.load` module. But this placeholder layer is still not exactly the same as the original Python code.

#### Use the `custom_objects` parameter on `tf.keras.models.load_model()`

It is possible to load a model with its original Python layers instead of the placeholder layers. Just pass a dictionary mapping layer names to Python layer class objects. This requires your code to be able to import the original Python layer. The example in my question can be fixed as follows:

```py
model3 = tf.keras.models.load_model(
    "model2",
    custom_objects=dict(
        CustomLayer=CustomLayer,
    ),
)
```

Make sure that your layer implements [`Layer.get_config()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#get_config) and returns a dictionary with all of the parameters needed to recreate the layer from scratch. The layer must be able to be recreated with `Layer.from_config()`.

#### Import the Python layer and add it to Keras's global registry

Keras maintains a global registry of custom Python classes and other objects to refer to when loading SavedModels. You can register your custom Keras layer with the [`@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/register_keras_serializable) decorator. For example:

```py
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(
   package="my_python_package"
)
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        return inputs
```

This method also requires that your layer properly implement `Layer.get_config()`.

#### Install the Python layer object with `tf.keras.utils.custom_object_scope()`

Much like the above two solutions, the [`tf.keras.utils.custom_object_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/custom_object_scope) context manager can specify which custom layers to use when deserialization.