# Could not deserialize class 'Generator' because its parent module networks cannot be imported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, serialization

I have a subclassed model `Generator` that uses other subclassed layers declared in a different file `ops.py`. I tried to save the model by calling `model.save()` in `keras` format. Now when I am trying to load the model by calling `tf.keras.models.load_model()`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Could not deserialize class 'Generator' because its parent module networks cannot be imported. Full object config: {'module': 'networks', 'class_name': 'Generator', 'config': {'name': 'Generator', 'max_conv_dim': 512, 'sn': False, 'img_size': 256, 'img_ch': 3, 'style_dim': 64}, 'registered_name': 'Generator', 'build_config': {'input_shape': [[8, 256, 256, 3], [8, 64]]}}
```

I am basically trying to save the `Generator` so that I can use it without importing the classes. This is the code that I am using: https://github.com/clovaai/stargan-v2-tensorflow

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762319/15019223